# What is TPID in email messages?

Tags: email

What is `TPID` in email messages exactly? How does it could be look or how could I generate it?

I tried google it but I didn't find a reliable answer.

Comment: Where are you seeing this?

Comment: I got a specification that I have to send custom email TPID. This is why I would like to understand what is it exactly.